# Visual Studio error could not refresh credentials

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

Hi everyone this is my first post. I am having a major problem with visual studio I cannot log in to extend my 30 day trial period and have no access to using visual studio. So here is what is happening exactly I have been using visual studio 2017 community version for 30 days as a trial, they want me to log in to extend the use of visual studio but I get an error for almost everything. I will show some screenshots as to what specific errors.

[Specific error with vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8tWs.jpg)

So those are my errors and like anyone else here would do I have tried multiple ways to fix this myself. Here is what I have done.

- I have gone into .Identityservice and cleared the cache that was there(there are multiple different forums and such detailing which cache to delete I only had one in the appdata/local/.identityservice which was IdentityServiceAdalCache.cache)
- I have tried to go around going into the visual studio installer then to report a problem to sign into the developer community, it will let me sign in however as soon as I am done signing it is says that I have logged out and need to refresh my credentials which is why I cannot post on the developer community directly as well.
- three clean reinstalls
- repair option in installer
- tried to see if updating would help

One more thing is that since visual studio provides error logs I have one here(or most of it anyway)
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5wes.jpg)

I would really appreciate any help I can get, I have scoured the internet looking for answers but haven't been able to find much. Hopefully I have provided enough information. Thank you.